# Dropdown menu php with next/previous button

Tags: php, mysql, session, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

I have :

```html
<select name="department" id="department" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <?php 
        do { 
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_department['dept_Name'] ?>"><?php echo $row_department['dept_Name'] == $department ? 'selected' : ''?><?php echo $row_department['dept_Name'] 
        ?></option>
    <?php
    } while ($row_department = mysql_fetch_assoc($department));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($department);
    if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($department, 0);
   $row_department = mysql_fetch_assoc($department);
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

For the dropdown from the database named `department`.

Once dropdown selected, multiple file sets will viewed from database such as `id, name, dept_name` with next/previous button.

The problem is, whenever i clicked next/previous button, there no files viewed.

Dropdown must be selected for the 2nd time for view 2nd file set.

What should I do and how? I'm using Dreamweaver CS6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You canno't search because you don't have a query to do that.

```
 $deptName = $row['dept_Name'];
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (table_name) WHERE (column_department_name) = '$deptName'");

  while ($row_department = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
   $rows = mysql_num_rows($row_department);
  if($rows > 0) {
     echo $rows['(your_column_name)'];
  }else{
      echo 'nothing';
  }
```